# Unable to send response to dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I have been working on the DialogFlow for quite sometime.I am facing a issue here.Also please note that,I am new to Node JS.

I  had a function to make HTTP calls since I need to those calls frequently with respect to my intent functions.Using Callback functions I got the resulting output back from the called function to the calling function.Everything is fine till here.Next,I want to send the returned reponse to the User using the "WebhookClient.add()".

But the problem with that one is,its not sending the response to user.But when i tried to print the returned value in log,it works fine.
I have even tried to copy the returned variable into a global variable and send it back to the user using WebhookClient.add() but it responds to the user as UNDEFINED as the value for the global variable.

The below is my code:

```js
 var doco;
 //My intent function
 function createSalesOrder(agent) {

        const soldTo = agent.parameters.soldTo;
        const shipTo = agent.parameters.shipTo;
        const customerPO = agent.parameters.custPO;
        const mcu = agent.parameters.mcu;
        const item = agent.parameters.item;
        const qty = agent.parameters.qty1;
        var doco1;
        
        orchName = 'JDE_ORCH_SALESORDER_GA';

        postData1 = {
            "inputs": [{
                "name": "Customer PO",
                "value": customerPO
            }, {
                "name": "Sold To",
                "value": soldTo
            }, {
                "name": "Ship To",
                "value": shipTo
            }, {
                "name": "BusinessUnit",
                "value": mcu
            }, {
                "name": "Item Number",
                "value": item
            }, {
                "name": "Quantity Ordered",
                "value": qty
            }]
        };
        postData = JSON.stringify(postData1);
        //Calling the external function for network call
        networkCall(postData,orchName,function(response){
             doco1 = response.ServiceRequest1.fs_P42101_W42101D.subforms.s_W42101D_S421007A_181.data.z_DOCO_137.value;
             console.log("DOCO "+doco1);
             doco = doco1;
             agent.add(`Document number is ${doco1}`);//Here the response is sent to dialogflow i.e google assistant is not reading this response to the user 
        });
        
        agent.add(`Document number is ${doco}`);//Here the value is read back to the user as UNDEFINED.But it has the value in a global variable
    }
```

The below is my called function:

```js
function networkCall(postData, orchName,callback) {
    
    const options = {
        hostname: '<hostname>',
        port: <port>,
        path: '<path>' + orchName,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
        },
        auth: 'user:pwd'
    };
    console.log("options:" + options);

    const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
        console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
        console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data = JSON.parse(chunk);
            console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
        });
        res.on('end', () => {
            callback(data);
            console.log('==END RESPONSE==');
        });
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
        console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
    });

    // write data to request body
    req.write(postData);
    req.end();
}
```

I would to repeat it again that in the calling function,the output which here is "doco1" is printed in the log but agent.add()is not invoked.Everything is working fine except that part.

Please guide me how can i send the value back to the user.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
I have changed my code to :

```js
//function call
return httpRequest(postData1)
        .then((message)=> {
             agent.add(`SUCCESS`);
                return Promise.resolve()
        })
       .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                agent.add("Uh oh, something happened.");
                return Promise.resolve();
            })
```

```js
//called function
var options = {
  method: 'post',
  uri: 'url',
  body: myJSONObject,
  auth: {
        'user': 'usr',
        'pass': 'pwd'
      },
  json: true
};
return rp( options )
  .then( body => {
  var doco =body.ServiceRequest1.fs_P42101_W42101D.subforms.s_W42101D_S421007A_181.data.z_DOCO_137.value;
 console.log('DOCO '+doco);
 
   
    return Promise.resolve( doco );
  })
  .catch( err => {
   console.log('FAILED'+err);
    // You should also return a message here of some sort
    return Promise.resolve( err );
  });
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined 
  at module.exports (/user_code/node_modules/request-promise-native/node_modules/request-promise-core/configure/request2.js:34:47) 
  at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/request-promise-native/lib/rp.js:15:1) 
  at Module._compile (module.js:577:32) 
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10) 
  at Module.load (module.js:494:32) at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12) at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
  at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
  at networkCall (/user_code/index.js:174:16)
Function execution took 663 ms, finished with status: 'crash'
```

the problem is with the package'request-promise-native'.Kindly help me how to import it and add dependency to it.I have added dependency as "request-promise-native":"*"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `networkCall()` is a function that does its job asynchronously, but the Dialogflow library assumes that if you're doing async operations that your handler will return a Promise. Since you don't return a Promise, as soon as your function returns, the response is sent to the user. Since your async call hasn't completed yet, it gets sent without the information.

You have a few solutions to your problem, but they all involve returning a Promise of some sort, so reading up on Promises will help.

What I would suggest is to modify `networkCall()` to return a Promise. The best way to do this is to replace `http.request()` with the [`request-promise-native`](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native) package. I haven't tested, but it might look something like this:

```
function networkCall(postData, orchName,callback) {

    const options = {
        hostname: '<hostname>',
        port: <port>,
        path: '<path>' + orchName,
        method: 'POST',
        body: postData,
        json: true,
        auth: 'user:pwd'
    };
    console.log("options:" + options);

    const rp = require('request-promise-native');
    return rp( options )
      catch( err => {
        console.err('Something went wrong in the call.',err);
        Promise.reject( err );
      });
};
```

then your call to it in `createSalesOrder()` would be something like

```
// Note I use postData1, since it takes the JSON object
return networkCall(postData1,orchName)
  .then( response => {
    var doco1 = response.ServiceRequest1.etc.etc.etc.value;
    console.log('DOCO '+doco1);
    return agent.add(`Document number is ${doco1}`);
  })
  .catch( err => {
    return agent.add('Something went wrong.);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried it but the app crashed.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at module.exports (/user_code/node_modules/request-promise-native/node_modules/request-promise-core/configure/request2.js:34:47)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/request-promise-native/lib/rp.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)

Comment: (Contd.) at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at networkCall (/user_code/index.js:174:16)

Function execution took 663 ms, finished with status: 'crash'

Comment: Check the parameters, since I'm not sure I got all of them correct. If you're still having problems update your original question to show what you're doing instead of trying to provide code or error messages in comments.

Comment: Also check what version of node.js you're using and if it supports native promises.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do check those things?It might sound naive but please help me out

Comment: You can update your original question by clicking on the "edit" link that is underneath the tags for your question. Add the additional information there and post a comment (typically after where someone asks for clarification) saying you've updated it.

Comment: If you are running node.js on your own machine you can type `node --version` on the command line to see the version. If you're using it on some other environment without a command line (for example, Google Cloud Functions or AWS Lambda), say that. Basically, any information we can get about the environment you're using will help.